# Динамически создать переменные и присвоить им значения из .txt

Tags: java

Есть текстовый файл в виде:

```
X1 = 1
X2 = 2
X3 = 3
X4 = 4
X5 = 5
X6 = 6
X7 = 7
X8 = 8
X9 = 9
X10 = 10
```

Что хочу сделать: получить из него данные и присвоить соответствующим переменным (т.е. будет 10 переменных `X1...X10` со значениями из файла).
С помощью регулярок вытаскиваю из файла данные и добавляю в `Map` в виде `<имя переменной, значение>`.

Вопрос: как динамически создать нужное количество переменных и присвоить им соответствующие значения?
И еще, как получить только `X1` и `1`, а не такое:

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=\w\d+ region=0,6 lastmatch=X1] java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=\d+ region=0,6 lastmatch=1]
```

Данные получаю так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String regex_variables = "\\w\\d+";
    final String regex_values = "\\d+";

    Pattern p_var = Pattern.compile(regex_variables);
    Pattern p_val = Pattern.compile(regex_values);
    Matcher m_var;
    Matcher m_val;

    Map<String, String> variables_values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String path = "inputs.txt";

    String s = null, i = null;

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            m_var = p_var.matcher(line);
            m_val = p_val.matcher(line);
            if (m_var.find() && m_val.find()) {
                s = m_var.toString();
                i = m_val.toString();
                variables_values.put(s, i);
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry entry: variables_values.entrySet()) { 
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Создавать переменные в runtim'е в java нельзя.

Comment: Что значит создать переменные динамически? Хэш-таблицу и используйте далее, получая нужное значение по ключу (имени переменной).

Comment: @PavelParshin не инициализировать их по одной, а как-нибудь в цикле, такое возможно?

Comment: Пройтись в цикле и инициализировать переменные таким образом нельзя. Чем не подходит использование `HashMap`?

Comment: @PavelParshin, подходит, просто не хотелось обращаться каждый раз к `HashMap`. Как из `Matcher`-a получить только значение поля `lastmatch` ?

Comment: вы не рассматривали вариант использования XML и xml-парсера ? Обычно для таких задач используют именно такую схему.

Comment: @pavlofff, хм..действительно, не подумал об этом сразу. Так будет проще?

Comment: Не только намного проще, но и гораздо правильнее.

Comment: А как вы потом к этим динамически созданным переменным обращаться планируете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае можно и не использовать регулярные выражения... используйте split()

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("text.txt");
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
        StringBuilder keys = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
            keys.append(line.split(" = ")[0]);
            value.append(line.split(" = ")[1]);
            keys.append(" ");
            value.append(" ");
        }
        reader.close();

        String[] keyArr = keys.toString().split(" ");
        String[] valueArr = value.toString().split(" ");

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(int x = 0; x<keyArr.length; x++){
            map.put(keyArr[x], Integer.parseInt(valueArr[x]));
        }

        System.out.println(map.get("X1"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить имя переменной и значение с помощью регулярных выражений, можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\w\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)");
```

Для каждой строки из файла в цикле создаем свой `Matcher`:

```
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String name = matcher.group(1);
    String value = matcher.group(2);
    variables_values.put(name, value);
} else {
    // TODO Обработка ошибки или просто игнорирование
}
```

---

Также, чтобы не изобретать велосипед, можно использовать класс [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), чтобы загрузить значения из `input.txt`:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try (Reader reader = new FileReader("inputs.txt")) {
    prop.load(reader);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

prop.list(System.out);
```

Метод [list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#list-java.io.PrintStream-) выводит все свойства и их значения. Получить значение можно с помощью метода [getProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) или метода [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get-java.lang.Object-), унаследованного от [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

```
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("X1"));
System.out.println(prop.get("X1"));
```